# How to get multiple line in a loop from a file?

Tags: c++

I want to get multiple lines sequentially from a file and then save them to a variable. If in Java can be using `scanner.nextInt`.

**How about C++?**

```
int main(){
        string line;
        int a, b, c;
        ifstream myFile("input.in");
        if(myFile.is_open()){
            while(getline(myFile,line)){
                int cases = atoi(line.c_str());
                double count[cases];
                cout << "cases : "<<cases << "\n";
                for(int i = 1; i <= cases; i++){
                    a = atoi(line.c_str());
                    b = atoi(line.c_str());
                    c = atoi(line.c_str());
                    cout << a << b << c;
                }
            }
        }        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How about `while (getline(myFile, line1) && getline(myFile, line2))`?

Comment: I also suggest you take a look at [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: And by the way, the equivalent to `scanner.nextInt` of Java is simply e.g. `myFile >> myInt`.

Comment: Lastly note that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Some compilers have it as an *extension* of the language, but it's not portable or should be counted on to exist everywhere. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: what does your input file look like?

Comment: Also instead of `atoi` and `line.c_str()` you might as well use `std::stoi()` directly on the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while(input.in >> cases)` to read the next int into `cases` until end of file (EOF) is reached. I've updated your code below.

```
int main(){
    string line;
    int a, b, c;
    ifstream myFile("input.in");
    if(myFile.is_open()) {
        int cases = 0;
        while(myFile >> cases) { // breaks on eof
            double count[cases];
            cout << "cases : " << cases << "\n";
            for(int i = 1; i <= cases; i++){
                myFile >> a;
                myFile >> b;
                myFile >> c;
                cout << a << b << c;
            }
        }
    }        
    return 0;
}
```